# Find $1+2 w+3 w^{2}+4 w^{3}+5 w^{4}$ given that $w^3+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

This is the question: Find the value of $1+2 w+3 w^{2}+4 w^{3}+5 w^{4}$ such that $w \neq-1$ is a complex root of $x^{3}+1=0$.

The given solution says this: Let $S=1+2 w+3 w^{2}+4 w^{3}+5 w^{4}$. Notice that this is an arithmetico-geometric series. In order for most of the coefficients be $1$, let us make another equation by multiplying $S$ with $w$.
$$S(w)=w+2 w^{2}+3 w^{3}+4 w^{4}+5 w^{5}$$
Subtracting the two equations, we have $S(1-w)=1+w+w^{2}+w^{3}+w^{4}-5 w^{5}$. Notice this equation can be rewritten as
$$S=\frac{1+w+w^{2}+w^{3}+w^{4}+w^{5}-6 w^{5}}{1-w} \Leftrightarrow\left(\left(w^{3}+1\right)\left(1+w+w^{2}\right)-6 w^{5}\right)(w)\\ =-6 w^{6}=-6$$
Now, I don't understand how we get the part after the $\Leftrightarrow$ . Can anyone explain?

Comment: It seems to me to be an interesting, but overly complicated solution. If $\omega^3=-1$ and $\omega\neq-1$, then $\omega^2-\omega+1=0$. From this you can reduce powers of $\omega$: $\begin{aligned}[t]&1+2\omega+3\omega^2+4\omega^3+5\omega^4\\&=1+2\omega+3\omega^2-4-5\omega\\&=-3-3\omega+3\omega^2\\&=-3(1+\omega-\omega^2)\\&=-3(1+\omega-\omega+1)\\&=-3(2)=-6\end{aligned}$

Comment: $S = 1 +2 \omega + 3 \omega^2 - 4 -  5 \omega = -3 - 3 \omega + 3 \omega^2$   and $ \omega^2 - \omega = -1$

Comment: @alex.jordan actually, there are two solutions given from this problem and yours is the second given. im trying to figure out the first solution (presented above) because i might encounter a similar problem again

Comment: You may simply re-group in the numerator:
\begin{align}
1+w+w^{2}+w^{3}+w^{4}+w^{5}&=(1+w^3)+(w+w^4)+(w^2+w^5)=\\&=1+w^3+w(1+w^3)+w^2(1+w^3)=\\
&=(1+w^3)(1+w+w^2)
\end{align}
But we also need $\frac{1}{1-w}=w$ to get somehow from $1+w^3=0$.

Comment: Actually from a mathematical perspective the second solution is the one you want to master, because that's the general method. The first solution depends on a rather exotic and rare numerical coincidence, i.e. that its an arithmetico-geometric series (I could not even type that properly at first, that's how exotic and rare it is). But, who knows, maybe contest-math people really want you to learn aritheot0-goemeti series.

Comment: Is "linear algebra" an appropriate tag for this question?

Comment: Yes, it should be $=$.

Answer (score 1):

$$1+w+w^{2}+w^{3}+w^{4}+w^{5}-6 w^{5}$$ is just rewritten as
$$\left(w^{3}+1\right)\left(1+w+w^{2}\right)-6 w^{5}$$

Also it's used the fact that $w^2-w+1=0$ to transform the denominator. since $1=w-w^2$ then $\frac{1}{w}=1-w$

Answer (score 1):

I think the $\iff$ sign is inappropriate, and should be an $=$ sign. Part of the numerator is factored, and division by $1-w$ is the same as multiplication by $w$, if you agree that $w^2-w+1=0$. (Because that is equivalent to $\frac{1}{1-w}=w$.)

Here are those lines with $\iff$ replaced by $=$, and a few "skipped steps" explained in more detail.

$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac{1+w+w^{2}+w^{3}+w^{4}+w^{5}-6 w^{5}}{1-w}\\
&=\frac{\left(w^{3}+1\right)\left(1+w+w^{2}\right)-6 w^{5}}{1-w}&&\text{(factoring)}\\
&=\left(\left(w^{3}+1\right)\left(1+w+w^{2}\right)-6 w^{5}\right)(w)&&((1-w)^{-1}=w)\\
&=\left(0(1+w+w^2)-6 w^{5}\right)(w)&&(w^3=-1)\\
&=-6w^6\\
&=-6(-1)^2\\
&=-6
\end{align}$$